# Using gcloud, how can I find the Virtual Machine Name?

Tags: virtual-machine, gcloud

I am trying to find the Google Cloud Compute Virtual Machine Name, using the gcloud command while logged in to the VM.

Me searching in the documentation didn't yield a result...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See [Metadata service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata).

Specifically:

```sh
curl \
--header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" \
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name
```

The Metadata service is a well-implemented API, you can navigate up-down the tree of resources, for example, dropping the final `name` from the above URL, enumerates all the resources under `instance`:

```sh
curl \
--header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" \
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/
```

returns:

```
attributes/
cpu-platform
description
disks/
guest-attributes/
hostname
id
image
legacy-endpoint-access/
licenses/
machine-type
maintenance-event
name
network-interfaces/
preempted
remaining-cpu-time
scheduling/
service-accounts/
tags
virtual-clock/
zone
```

You can then pick any of the above, append it to the URL to continue browsing.

The documentation in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) is similarly comprehensive and, in the case of instance metadata, as expected, reflects the response from GET'ing

https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/.../instances/...

i.e.:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get#response-body